# jQuery Why dynamically added images are not getting shown/hidded on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to write a code that will show an link icon when hovered over a title encapsulated inside

What I did is, I had a CSS class `samplea`. Had many `<a>` with `class='samplea'`. Then I inserted jQuery to add custom link image after `<a>`. I hided the image initially. And then added jQuery so that it will be shown/hidden when hovered over title.

However am able to insert image after all `<a class='samplea'>` but not able to hide/show them.

**HTML**

```
<h3><a class="samplea"  id="aid">Sample Title</a></h3>
<h3><a class="samplea"  id="a1">Sample Title</a></h3>
<h3><a class="samplea"  id="a1">Sample Title</a></h3>
```

**CSS**

```
.samplea {  
    }
```

**JS**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var permalinkid = 1;
        $(".samplea").each(function (index) {
            $(this).after("&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='http://www.spotzerblog.com/wp-content/themes/StandardTheme_261/images/icn_permalink.png' id='permalink" + permalinkid + "' />");
            //if you comment below line it will show the link icons 
            //appropriately
            $("#permalink" + permalinkid).hide();                
            $(this).hover(
                   function () { $("#permalink" + permalinkid).show(); },
                   function () { $("#permalink" + permalinkid).hide(); }
            );
            permalinkid = permalinkid + 1;               
        });
    });
```

Why is it so? Here is the corresponding [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mahesha999/G3Psm/1/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
// New way (jQuery 1.7+) - .on(events, selector, handler)
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', 'h3', function () {
    $(this).find('img').toggle();
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/G3Psm/2/)

Comment: The issue is quite simple. If you look at this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/G3Psm/6/) and open your console, you will see that on hover of the h3 elements you always get in console `Mouseenter: 4 
Mouseleave: 4` and you don't have any element with _ID_ `permalink4`. This happens since the hover method is evaluated by the jQuery at the last when you have the `permalinkid` variable as 4.

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing `permalinkid = permalinkid + 1` in every iteration, however it gets evaluated only when you go the "hover" which will make it `permalink4`
http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/G3Psm/5/
The answer of Palash Mondal is solving your problem essentially, however if you would like to keep it ID based, then check this:
http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/G3Psm/9/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var permalinkid = 1;
    $(".samplea").each(function (index) {
        var temp = permalinkid;
        $(this).after($("<div id='permalink" + temp + "'>text</div>"));
        //if you comment below line it will show link icon
        //appropriately        
        $("#permalink" + permalinkid).hide();
        $(this).hover(

        function () {
            $("#permalink" + temp).show();
        },

        function () {
            $("#permalink" + temp).hide();
        });
        permalinkid = permalinkid + 1;
    });
});
```

Comment: didnt get you, can u please elaborate?

Comment: Check the fiddle in my answer. The `$("#permalink" + permalinkid).show();` will be `$("#permalink4").show();` when the hover is happening...